# HardwareButtons_BackPressed doesn't work on secondary page

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I have a Windows Phone 8.1 app. It consists of 2 pages. On the first page (MainPage.xaml) there is ListView and few buttons. One buton allow to multiselect items on the list. In code I handle back buton, so when user click back in multiselection mode the app won't terminate, but just exit the multiselection mode.

```
private void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, BackPressedEventArgs e)
{
    if (MultiSelectionButton.Visibility == Visibility.Collapsed)
    {
        DeleteSelectionButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        MultiSelectionButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        TripListView.SelectionMode = ListViewSelectionMode.None;
        TripListView.IsItemClickEnabled = true;

        e.Handled = true;
    }
}

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
    this.navigationHelper.OnNavigatedTo(e);
}

protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    HardwareButtons.BackPressed -= HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
    this.navigationHelper.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
}
```

On the second page (HubPage.xaml) there is Hub control, HubSection, and in the HubSection ListView. Similar to the first page I dont want to go back to previous page from selection mode.

```
private void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, BackPressedEventArgs e)
{
       if (_PeopleListViewInstance.SelectionMode == ListViewSelectionMode.Multiple)
       {
            _PeopleListViewInstance.SelectionMode = ListViewSelectionMode.None;
             DeleteSelectionButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
             MultiSelectionButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
             _PeopleListViewInstance.IsItemClickEnabled = true;

             e.Handled = true;
       }
 }

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
      _vm.Trip = (Trip) e.Parameter;
      DataContext = _vm;

      HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
      this.navigationHelper.OnNavigatedTo(e);
}

protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
     HardwareButtons.BackPressed -= HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
     this.navigationHelper.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
}
```

Code on the first page works fine, but the second one doesn't.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Check whether BackPressed  event registering correctly in second page by putting breakpoints. And unregister first page event before navigating to second page. OnNavigatedFrom is called after navigating to Secondpage. Possibility of unregistering  second page BackPressed event is there.

Comment: as you are handling hardware back button. than stop using navigationHelper. on your Hubpage constructure comment/remove initialinzing navigationHelper and rmove this.navigationHelper.OnNavigatedTo(e); from NavigateTo and NavigateFrom  eventHandlers

Comment: comment/remove below line in Hubpage.xaml.cs
 //this.navigationHelper = new NavigationHelper(this);